# Scheduling a GUI program task and showing its GUI at login

Tags: windows

Following Marcus's accepted answer on the topic of scheduling a GUI program to strart on system startup and show its GUI when logging in-

https://serverfault.com/questions/583517/start-program-on-computer-startup-when-nobody-is-logged-on-and-show-the-window-w

I am able to do so but not all the way; In my server I need to activate Xamp and another java program which is the main acpplication, on startup, and see their GUI when I'm logged in. The accepted answer suggest to use an Autologn program to auto logon on startup, then launch the program by task triggered by login. I tested it with a program and it worked. But in my scenario I scheduled  a task as explained, to launch both Xamp and my app, but when logged in, I can only see the GUI of Xamp, the java application only then (when I logged in) is activated.

I tried different tasks for Xamp and for my app, I tried sigle task for them both, I tried launching a batch file to launch them both,I tried convert my java app to exe, nothing helped, still the same result. For some reason it works for the Xamp (and another application I tested it with) and not for my app.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** - I just noticed that only when I'm loggin in, the Xamp activation is completed, (it prompts additional output) and only then my app is launched. How can I handle such a behaviour?